# Div getting larger instead of scrollbar on page

Tags: html, scrollbar

I've created a website with a content-width of 800px.

However, when my user uploads a picture with a width of 900px, the site is totally out of order.
Is there a way to add a slider or scrollbar instead of the div getting bigger, when the images are too large for the website? If not, I think I have to resize the uploaded images..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that because you're talking about width, that you're wanting the content width to maintain at 800px and then default to scroll if content (in this case an image) is > 800px.

Perhaps you could take advantage of the **overflow-x: scroll;** property in CSS to only scroll horizontally. **overflow: auto;** may add the vertical scroll as well when not required.

Answer (score 2):

put `style="overflow:auto;"` on your div then it will produce a scroll bar when image is larger than your space

Answer (score 0):

You may need to supply a little bit of the code that you are using so we can figure out the problem, but what you could use is:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

That will stop anything being wider than your 800px content container.